# PyQt5 QListView has stoped loading entries from QSqlTableModel and I don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

**Updated info at bottom of post.**

I need a bit of help with PyQt5 and its model view architecture for databases.

I am trying to re-make a database project I did. (https://github.com/DivineHermit/Media-Database-v1/) updating it to use models (https://github.com/DivineHermit/Media-Database-v2/).

I currently have three QSqlTableModel one for each table in the database:

1) model_media is a QSqlTableModel of the 'media' table in my database and currently has 616 entries and is used by the QListView on the main window and by a QDataWidgetMapper to display detailed info about the selected entry.

2) model_genres another QSqlTableModel for the 'genres' table.

3) model_types a final QSqlTableModel for the 'media_types' table.

However, after setting up the second and third models (displaying their data on child windows) the original model has stopped loading entries when scrolling down the list view and I can't figure out why, before it would load a few entries and then load some more when you scrolled to the end of the QListView.

**Clarification (I hope):**
The original model 'model_media' is used to display a list of media titles in a QListView (it currently has 616 entries) it would display the first hundred or so entries in the QListView and as I scrolled down it would load more, just as expected. So I moved on to implement the next two models and similarly display their data on their own windows which worked out fine, however, at this point the main QListView no longer loaded entries when scrolling down the list, it only displays the first hundred or so entries.

Original Project (PyQt5 & Sqlite3): https://github.com/DivineHermit/Media-Database-v1/

New Version (PyQt5 Only): https://github.com/DivineHermit/Media-Database-v2/

**Update: Test scripts.**

I currently believe the way I implemented my class/GUI is interfering with the main model and will be stripping the project down to the basics and trying to implement some testing to find the true problem.

I am including the test scripts below hoping they'll be of help to others.

Following eyllanesc's suggestion I wrote out a minimal example of the models I am using and ran it against the database trying to reproduce the error, however, this test script actually worked:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtSql
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class DBQueries(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, db="Media-Database.db", parent=None):
        super(DBQueries, self).__init__(parent)
        self.db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName(db)
        if not self.db.open():
            print("Error connecting to database:\n{}".format(self.db.lastError().text()))
        # ===== Media Model =====
        self.model_media = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model_media.setTable("media")
        self.model_media.sort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model_media.select()
        # ===== Genres Model =====
        self.model_genres = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model_genres.setTable("genres")
        self.model_genres.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model_genres.select()
        # ===== Types Model =====
        self.model_types = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.model_types.setTable("media_types")
        self.model_types.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.model_types.select()
        # ===== Proxy/Search Model =====
        self.proxy = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model_media)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(1)
        self.proxy.setFilterCaseSensitivity(QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        # ===== UI =====
        self.cw = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.cw)
        self.le_search = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.le_search.textChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.proxy.setFilterFixedString(
                self.le_search.text()))
        self.vl.addWidget(self.le_search)

        self.view_media_list = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.view_media_list.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view_media_list.setModelColumn(1)  # Title column.
        self.vl.addWidget(self.view_media_list)

        self.view_media = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view_media.setModel(self.proxy)
        self.view_media.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.view_media)

        self.cb_genres = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.cb_genres.setModel(self.model_genres)
        self.cb_genres.setModelColumn(1)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.cb_genres)

        self.view_genres = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view_genres.setModel(self.model_genres)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.view_genres)

        self.cb_types = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.cb_types.setModel(self.model_types)
        self.cb_types.setModelColumn(1)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.cb_types)

        self.view_types = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        self.view_types.setModel(self.model_types)
        self.vl.addWidget(self.view_types)

        # ===== Selected =====
        self.selected_media = self.view_media.selectionModel()
        self.selected_media.selectionChanged.connect(self.display_details)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)

    def display_details(self):
        """Display a dialog with table cell contents, this is just a PoC."""
        details = QtWidgets.QDialog(self)
        details.setMinimumWidth(250)
        lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(details)
        lbl.setText(str(self.selected_media.currentIndex().data()))
        details.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Added an input to make t easier to swap
    #  between project and test databases.
    db = input("Enter name of database >>> ")
    window = DBQueries(db)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Realizing people willing to help won't have the database I'm using for the project I created the following script and used the test script against the new database with the same positive/working result:

```py
import sqlite3
import random

__author__ = "Dominic Lee"
__version__ = "0.0.1"


class DBGenerator:
    """Used to create an sqlite3 database with random data for testing."""

    def __init__(self, db_name=":memory:", count=1000):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_name)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.file_name = db_name
        self.create_media_table()
        self.create_genres_table()
        self.create_types_table()
        self.create_test_entries(count)
        self.create_test_genres()
        self.create_test_types()

    def create_media_table(self):
        """Create the main media table."""
        self.cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
            title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
            description VARCHAR,
            age_rating VARCHAR,
            genre VARCHAR,
            season INTEGER,
            disc_count INTEGER,
            media_type VARCHAR,
            play_time INTEGER,
            notes VARCHAR)""")
        self.connection.commit()
        return True

    def create_genres_table(self):
        """Create the genres table."""
        self.cursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS genres (
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            genre VARCHAR,
            description VARCHAR,
            examples VARCHAR)""")
        self.connection.commit()
        return True

    def create_types_table(self):
        """Create the media_types table."""
        self.cursor.execute("""
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media_types (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        type VARCHAR)""")
        self.connection.commit()
        return True

    def create_test_entries(self, count=1000):
        """
        Add randomized dummy data to database for testing
        :param count: the number of entries to add.
        :return: True
        """
        for i in range(1, count+1):
            print(f"Adding entry: {str(i).zfill(len(str(count)))}")
            self.cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO media VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
            """, (None,
                  f"Entry {str(i).zfill(len(str(count)))}",
                  f"Blank Description {str(i).zfill(len(str(count)))}",
                  f"{random.choice(['U: Universal', '15', '18', 'E: Exempt'])}",
                  f"{random.choice(['Action', 'Comedy', 'Drama', 'Sci-Fi'])}",
                  random.randint(0, 10),
                  random.randint(1, 6),
                  f"{random.choice(['DVD: Movie', 'DVD: Series', 'Audio CD', 'PS4 Game'])}",
                  random.randint(60, 1000),
                  f"Starring: {random.choice(['John', 'Paul', 'George', 'Ringo'])}"))
        self.connection.commit()
        return True

    def create_test_genres(self):
        """Add a list of genres to the database for testing purposes."""
        genres = ["Action",
                  "Anime",
                  "Biography",
                  "Cartoon",
                  "Comedy: Action",
                  "Comedy: Quiz Show",
                  "Comedy: Sitcom",
                  "Comedy: Stand-Up",
                  "Cookery",
                  "D.I.Y.",
                  "Documentary",
                  "Drama",
                  "Drama: Criminal",
                  "Educational",
                  "Fantasy",
                  "Game Show",
                  "Gardening",
                  "Horror",
                  "Kids/Children",
                  "Lifestyle",
                  "Makeover",
                  "Music",
                  "Mystery",
                  "News",
                  "Reality TV",
                  "Sci-Fi",
                  "Shopping",
                  "Soap",
                  "Talk Show",
                  "Thriller",
                  "Travel",
                  "Western"]
        for g in genres:
            print(f"Adding genre: {g}")
            self.cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO genres VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
            """, (None, g, f"Description for {g}", f"Examples for {g}"))
        self.connection.commit()
        return True

    def create_test_types(self):
        """Add media types to the database."""
        types = ["Audio CD",
                 "Book: Educational",
                 "Book: Graphic Novel",
                 "Book: Manga",
                 "Book: Novel",
                 "Book: Programming",
                 "Cassett Tape",
                 "DVD: Movie",
                 "DVD: Series",
                 "Digital Download",
                 "Nintendo DS Game",
                 "Nintendo Wii Game",
                 "PC Game",
                 "PS1 Game",
                 "PS2 Game",
                 "PS3 Game",
                 "PS4 Game",
                 "PSP Game",
                 "PSVita Game"]
        for t in types:
            print(f"Adding media type: {t}")
            self.cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO media_types VALUES (?, ?)
            """, (None, t))
        self.connection.commit()
        return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Create an instance of DBGenerator,
    # give it a name and how many entries to create.
    # DBGenerator(db_name, count)
    # db_name defaults to ':memory:'
    # count defaults to 1000
    db = DBGenerator(count=1000)
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I wrote out a minimal example and tested it against my database to try and reproduce the problem and it works. So I can only assume the error is in my original implementation. I'll post what I have as soon as I get the chance and will update/answer the original question when I figure out what I did wrong. Thanks & sorry to waste your time.

Comment: What is the problem? You could be more specific, that is, take the code you have provided based on.

Comment: I've tried to clarify the problem and be more specific. I apologize for the confusion, as you can see I'm rather new to stackoverflow and asking for help in general. I am currently re-writing the project trying to use the above test script as a base to see what stops the QListView from loading properly.

Comment: I still don't understand you, the "media" table has only 100 elements, where do you plan to get more items?

Comment: The database I have, has 616 entries the QListView on the main window should display the title of each entry it only shows the first 200. I tested this with the above database generator creating a database with 5000 entries the QListView only loads 257 entries.

Comment: However, I am halfway though re-writing the program using the above test script as a foundation and it seems to be working correctly, even a test database with 5000 entries loads.